# updating column with Integer instead of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and I want to iterate over only the 2nd column of that dataframe which is a list of tuples. I want to extraxt only the last element of each tuple from that list

I have made the script for text matching using fuzzywuzzy.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz



pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)

data = pd.read_csv(r"address_details.csv", skiprows=0)
id = data['COD_CUST_ID'].values.tolist()
address = data['ADDRESS'].values.tolist()

dict_list=[]

for i in range(0,len(id)):
    for add in range(0,len(address)):
        score=process.extractBests(address[add], address, limit=len(address), score_cutoff=40)
        #print(score)

        dict_={}
        dict_.update({"Cust_Id": id[i]})
        dict_.update({"Match Ratio": score})
        dict_.update({"Search String": address[add]})
        #dict_.update({"Address List": address})

        dict_list.append(dict_)

df=pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
print(df)

s=df.to_csv("match_score.csv",sep=',',index=None)
```

**Original csv data**

```
Cust_Id Match Ratio Search String
21527575    [('H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302', 100)]    H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    [('H.NO.407, ROOM NO.310, 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT OPP,RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOTER GATE THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302', 100)]   H.NO.407, ROOM NO.310, 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT OPP,RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOTER GATE THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    [('FLAT NO.103, 1ST FLOOR B-WING,CTS NO.388,KAAP TALAVO  ZAITOON PURA BEHIND KOTER GATE MASJID BHIWANDI THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302', 100)]    FLAT NO.103, 1ST FLOOR B-WING,CTS NO.388,KAAP TALAVO  ZAITOON PURA BEHIND KOTER GATE MASJID BHIWANDI THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    [('VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302', 100)]  VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302
21527575    [('WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302', 100)]  WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21527575    [('H.NO.-137 RAMA ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302', 100)]   H.NO.-137 RAMA ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21527575    [('WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001', 100)]    WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001
21527575    [('Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 100)] Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803
21527575    [('VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 100)] VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803
21527575    [('VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307', 100)] VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Cust_Id Match Ratio Search String
21527575    100 H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    100 H.NO.407, ROOM NO.310, 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT OPP,RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOTER GATE THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    100 FLAT NO.103, 1ST FLOOR B-WING,CTS NO.388,KAAP TALAVO  ZAITOON PURA BEHIND KOTER GATE MASJID BHIWANDI THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
21527575    100 VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302
21527575    100 WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21527575    100 H.NO.-137 RAMA ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21527575    100 WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001
21527575    100 Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803
21527575    100 VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803
21527575    100 VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name is unclear so I am writing the general code.

In this, I am updating column B by the 3rd element of the tuple.

Hope it helps:)

```
 df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0][1])
```

Sample Program ::

```
import pandas as pd
Cars = {'A': [21527575],
        'B': [[('H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302', 100)]],
        'C' : [' H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302']
        }
data = pd.DataFrame(Cars)

data['B'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0][1])
print(data)
```

Output ::

```
     A    B                                                  C
0  21527575  100   H.NO.407,ROOM NO.310. 3RD FLOOR MAQBOOL APARTMENT APARTMENT OPP, RABIYA MASJID MANGAL BAZAR SLAP KOT THANE MAHARASHTRA 421302
```

Comment: Works perfect brother. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries Bro :)

Comment: Bro it would be really kind of you if you could help me figure out the solution for this question too https://stackoverflow.com/q/56659979/11312863

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe was a bit unclear.

See if this solves your issue.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data frame
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [[(1, 2)], [(2, 3)], [(3, 4)]]})
print(data)

# Data
   a         b
0  1  [(1, 2)]
1  2  [(2, 3)]
2  3  [(3, 4)]

# Fix
# [-1] selects last element in tuple
data['b'] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: x[0][-1])
print(data)

# Result
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```