# Get ids with similar address in a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from which i process some columns to get the matching percentage of address of each customer id with address of every other customer id. If some addresses match the other addresses with percentage above 80 then I want to gather their corresponding customer ids in a new column

I have made the code in which i get the list of tuples having the address and their corresponding scores in each tuple.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process


def pat_match(id,address):

    length01=len(id)    # normal integer sequence 1 to 10


    for y in range(0,length01):
        score=process.extractBests(address[y],address,score_cutoff=80)
        print(score)                    # actual results(list of tuples)
        d2=[sc[1] for sc in score]
        #print(d2)                       # variable having list of scores per address tuple



if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv(r"address_details.csv", skiprows=0)
    id = data['COD_CUST_ID'].values.tolist()
    address = data['ADDRESS'].values.tolist()
    pat_match(id,address)
```

Suppose I have an input data as

```
Customer_ID Address
21213944    VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302
21991538    WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21991539    H.NO.-137 RAMA ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302
21603327    VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803
21215934    VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307
```

And the intermediate output of the variable SCORE is

```
[('WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001', 100), ('VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302', 86), ('WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302', 86), ('H.NO.-137 RAMA ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302', 86), ('Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 86)]
[('Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 100), ('VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 91), ('WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001', 86), ('VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307', 86)]
[('VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 100), ('Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 91), ('WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001', 86), ('VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307', 86)]
[('VILLAGE GORIYAN TEHSIL UDAIPURWATI DIST JHUNJHUNU  JHUJHUNU RAJASTHAN 333307', 100), ('VPO. SAHWA   CHURU RAJASTHAN 331302', 86), ('WARD NO 25 GHADSISAR ROAD BASANT KUNJ KE SAMNE HANUMAN MANDIR KE PASS CHOUDHARY COLONY GANGASHAR BIKANER RAJASTHAN 334001', 86), ('Karchha Kalan   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 86), ('VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803', 86)]
```

The final output I want to be is like

```
Search String   Match Customer Ids
WARD NO.-3 NATT ROAD TALWANDI SABO BATHINDA  BATHINDA PUNJAB 151302 21991538,21991539
VAGPUR KARCHCHA KALAN   UDAIPUR RAJASTHAN 313803    21603327,21215934
```

Comment: Okay..! So you are able to get the address which is having match percentage with more than 80% score and you only want to add one another column to original dataframe consisting of the customer id of that address with match score of more than 80% . Am i correct?

Comment: @0xPrateek Brother u r absolutely correct. I am really sorry for my late reply. But i'll check ur code below and update you soon. Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: df['COD_CUST_ID'][df['ADDRESS']==matched_ids[0]].tolist()[0] This line throws List index out of range error brother. I changed 'Customer_ID' to 'COD_CUST_ID' and 'Address' to 'ADDRESS' as these were the actual column names

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a look `get = df['Customer_ID'][df['Address']==address[y]].tolist()[0]
`

Comment: which line shall i print to see the final output

Comment: You can Directly print `df` at the end of the function. `print(df)`

Comment: Does that helps ?

Comment: what? did u change something in the code?

Comment: Yes, earlier it was `df['COD_CUST_ID'][df['ADDRESS']==matched_ids[0]].tolist()[0] ` and now it's `get = df['Customer_ID'][df['Address']==address[y]].tolist()[0] ` .

Comment: @0xPrateek If we replace COD_CUST_ID with Customer_ID and ADDRESS with Address then it gives KeyError. (KeyError: 'Customer_ID')

Comment: Change the column names as per you are having. I have update a line in the code it will work check.

Comment: In code I have changed address[y] to matched_address and it will work for sure....

Comment: @0xPrateek brother the code again gives List index out of range error. i debugged the code and saw that the loop was not iterating for all the customer ids.Maybe because of that this issue occurs

Comment: Can you share your dataset with me, pr4t333k@gmail.com I will help you out with that better.

Comment: ok...sharing in a minute

Comment: @0xPrateek i have sent the dataset on your mail

Comment: @0xPrateek Great Work bro :) Thanks a ton. U r really great at your Python Skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your problem, this solution will work, Code is self-explanatory :)

```
# Getting the DataFrame as the parameter
def pat_match(df):

    # Getting the column values of id and address in seprate list
    id = df['COD_CUST_ID'].values.tolist()
    address = df['ADDRESS'].values.tolist()

    # Creating a new column with name 'Ids'
    df['Ids'] = ""
    length01=len(id)   

    for y in range(0,length01):

        # The mathched address Id will will be appended in a list for every address
        matched_ids = []

        # Calculating list of address with match percentage more than 80%
        score=process.extractBests(address[y],address,score_cutoff=80)

        # Iterating over every address returned by score one by one
        for matched_address in score:

            # Getting Customer_ID of every Address
            get = df['Customer_ID'][df['Address']==matched_address].tolist()[0]

            # Appending the Id into a list
            matched_ids.append(get)

        # Finally Appending the list of matched ID to the column 
        df['Ids'][df['Customer_ID']==id[y]] = str(matched_ids)
```

main function :

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv(r"address_details.csv", skiprows=0)
    pat_match(data)
```